# R seq.POSIXt: Generate regular sequence by hour ignoring changes to/from daylight savings time

Tags: r

I am using this simple code to generate a sequence of hourly time steps between two dates:

```
dates <- strftime(seq(ISOdate(2015, 1, 1, 0, tz = "GMT"), ISOdate(2015, 12, 31, 23, tz = "GMT"), by = "hour"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The problem is that I don't want to generate these hours taking into account changes to/from daylight savings time.

I saw in the documentation that I can generate sequences of days using the "by = 'day'" or "by = 'DSTday'" argument but I don't see a similar option for the hours...

I have also read that using "tz = 'UTC'" could solve the problem but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how it's possible to do that? Thanks

Comment: Interesting question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found it. One can use the `dst` function in the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 0:00:00", tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct("2015-12-31 23:00:00", tz="UTC"), by="hour")
dates[dst(dates)] <- dates[dst(dates)] - 3600
```

I would be interested in a solution using the base packages, though...

Answer (score 1):

To add an upgrade based on Marc solution, I think a functional procedure is :

```
dates <- dates - dst(dates)*3600.
```